# How do we prevent warning from printing strange text at the end of its message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling, warnings

The following causes some additional strange output to be printed

```
import warnings

def foo(x):

    if x > 100:
        msg = "Warning! x is big!"
        warnings.warn(msg)
    return True

foo(999999)
```

Instead of only printing:

```
UserWarning: Warning! x is big!
```

we get:

```
UserWarning: Warning! x is big!
   warnings.warn(msg)
```

Sometimes I have even gotten:

```
UserWarning: Warning! x is big!
   ValueError [blah, blah, blah]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
import warnings
import sys

if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

def foo(x):

    if x > 100:
        msg = "Warning! x is big!"
        warnings.warn(msg)
    return True

foo(999999)
```

**Disclaimer**

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.warnoptions) advises not to change this setting:

> *sys.warnoptions*
>
> This is an implementation detail of the warnings
>   framework; do not modify this value. Refer to the warnings module for
>   more information on the warnings framework.